# Windows phone send file

Tags: windows-phone-8

In Android i can use ACTION_SEND (Intent mSendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)).
On start Intent user can select where and how send file email, dropbox (all applications that can be sent through).

Have the same functionality in Windows Phone?

Answer (score 2):

Not really. You can use the [ShareMediaTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207027%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to share a media file (it will give the user a choice of apps that can share medias, like twitter, facebook, etc.), but only a media file.

You can offer a file to the system to be opened in an associated application using [Launcher.LaunchFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701465.aspx) but that is not what you want I guess.

Comment: Thanks. I go with android in search of happiness, and then even more restrictive :(. Can I send email with attachment and WP account? Can I write custom Launcher/Chooser?

Comment: You cannot write a custom Launcher/Chooser. You cannot use the EmailComposeTask with an attachment

Comment: And what i can in my??? phone :). Can I use Google Account (MS, FB etc) added in phone to authorize on custom site with OAuth (or etc.) Some as 1. Ask user about added account 2. Authorize without user/pass (get token) 2. use token?

Comment: You do not have access to the accounts in the phone (like in iOS). You need to implement the login by yourself.